# Android Studio - why import statement is unused/not needed?

Tags: java, android, import, library-project

In an Android studio library project, the following code piece gives error.

```
package my.package.a;

import my.package.b.Test;  //this shows unused, why??

public class **Test** extends my.package.b.Test { //"Test is already defined in this compilation unit." why? 
    ...
}
```

1. `extends my.package.b.Test` this line is using package b, isn't it? so why the import statement shows unused?
2. These two `Test` classes are in different packages, why does it have name conflicts??

Solution:

1. Refer to full name and delete `import` statement.
2. Cannot import `my.package.b.Test` as it's in conflict with current class name.

Comment: What happens if you leave out the `import` statement?

Comment: @JamesKPolk Nothing changes if I remove the import statement.

Comment: Well when I remove the import it compiles without errors.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Oh you meant the name conflicts error. I tried removing import again and the error disappears. (wonder why I didn't find out earlier) Thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The import is not needed here because you're already calling out `my.package.b.Test` by full name.  If you use the fully qualified reference to a symbol, there is no need to import it.